# How to get rid of "Device is not Certified"?

Tags: google-play-services, google-apps

I wanted to ask that is there any solution for getting rid of this "Device is not Certified" without/with root? I have flashed Phusson's GSI and then GApps Micro but the first error j get is that on Setup screen, it sticks on Checking for Update no matter how much time I give it to check(Problem 1). The second problem is that I have sent the Android device ID (or whatever) used to certify the device but if no avail. It's still saying not Certified. I can spoof it by Magisk, that it is Certified by a module ummm... I forgot it's name(but it's not PlayStore Visa for sure) but still I can't use Google Play services in my device. Whenever I use an app that requires so, it gives an error that "Google Play Services is having trouble .....". What can I do to resolve this issue and use Google Play Services? (I have Redmi S2 but the issue seems to be on all devices)

Comment: Read an article somewhere that stated when you register with google it will still say not certified. However, Google white list your device so you can download and use Google apps. `Your device will still say it is uncertified in the Google Play Store settings. This is normal. All this fix does is white-list your uncertified device so you can still use Google apps and services.` https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-fix-device-not-certified-by-google-error/

Comment: @Bo Lawson but still, the Google services aren't working properly as I have specified the error in the question.

Comment: Google Apps ( GAPPS ) is a proprietary software bundle that requires a licence to distribute... However you can use Open GAPPS ( OGAPPS ) for devices that require the Open Software... https://opengapps.org/

Comment: @Gadget Guru I have flashed Open Google Apps on which this is the problem.

Comment: Apparently you can get an Xposed module for it, however i personally do not like installing a system level hack called xposed of all things.